# Strictly convex function solutions

Tags: calculus

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. We know that $f$ is a strictly convex function. Could we affirm that $f$ has, at most, two solutions of the form $f(x) = 0$ ?

Comment: Solutions to what?

Comment: Solutions like f(x) = 0

Comment: No. $f(x)=e^x$ is continuous and convex but $e^x \neq 0$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField ""at most two"

Comment: @CyclotomicField Then, f has at most two solutions. My question is if f could have more than two solutions.

Comment: The constant function $f(x) := 0$ is continuous and convex but has infinitely many solutions $x$ for $f(x)=0$.

Comment: Are you sure $f(x) := 0$ is convex?

Comment: Constant functions are convex. Are you maybe thinking of strictly convex?

Comment: Yes, I mean strictly convex functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function is at least $C^2$ then we can interpret this as $f''(x) > 0$. In this case, suppose $f(x_i) = 0$ for some $x_1 < x_2 < x_3$. By the mean value theorem,

$$ \frac{f(x_2) - f(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1} = 0 \implies \exists y_1 \in (x_1,x_2) \text{ so that } f'(y_1) = 0$$
and
$$ \frac{f(x_3) - f(x_2)}{x_3 - x_2} = 0 \implies \exists y_2 \in (x_2,x_3) \text{ so that } f'(y_2) = 0.$$

Now we use the mean value theorem again to get

$$\frac{f'(y_1) - f'(y_2)}{y_1 - y_2} = 0 \implies \exists z \in (y_1, y_2) \text{ so that } f''(z) = 0.$$

This contradicts strict convexity.

Edit: Here's a fast proof with no regularity assumptions. Notice that for all $y \in (x_1, x_2)$ we have

$$ f(tx_1 + (1-t)x_2) < t f(x_1) + (1-t) f(x_2) = 0.$$

The same apply for $x \in (x_2, x_3)$. Let $y_1 \in (x_1, x_2)$ and $y_2 \in (x_2, x_3)$. There is some $t$ so that $ty_1 + (1-t)y_2 = x_2$. Notice that
$$f(x_2) = f(ty_1 + (1-t)y_2) < t f(y_1) + (1-t)f(y_2) < 0 = f(x_2).$$
This is a contradiction.

Comment: The second proof also tells you something interesting for just convex functions: Either there are at most two zeroes or infinitely many zeroes.

Comment: It's not necessary for the function to be differentiable.

Comment: Yep, see the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proof without any differentiability assumptions.  If $\ f\ $ has at most one root then it certainly has at most two roots. Suppose then that $\ f\ $ has two distinct roots $\ x_1<x_2\ $.

If $\ x<x_1\ $, then
\begin{align}
0&=f(x_1)\\
&=f\left(\left(\frac{x_2-x_1}{x_2-x} \right)x+ \left(\frac{x_1-x}{x_2-x}\right)x_2\right)\\
&< \left(\frac{x_2-x_1}{x_2-x} \right)f(x)+ \left(\frac{x_1-x}{x_2-x}\right)f(x_2)\\
&= \left(\frac{x_2-x_1}{x_2-x} \right)f(x)\ ,
\end{align}
which implies $\ f(x)>0\ $.

If $\ x_1<x<x_2\ $, then
\begin{align}
f(x)&=f\left(\left(\frac{x_2-x}{x_2-x_1}\right)x_1+ \left(\frac{x-x_1}{x_2-x_1}\right)x_2\right)\\
&< \left(\frac{x_2-x}{x_2-x_1}\right)f(x_1)+ \left(\frac{x-x_1}{x_2-x_1}\right)f(x_2)\\
&=0\ .
\end{align}
If $\ x_2<x\ $, then
\begin{align}
0&=f(x_2)\\
&=f\left(\left(\frac{x-x_2}{x-x_1} \right)x_1+ \left(\frac{x_2-x_1}{x-x_1}\right)x\right)\\
&< \left(\frac{x-x_2}{x-x_1} \right) f(x_1)+ \left(\frac{x_2-x_1}{x-x_1}\right) f(x)\\
&= \left(\frac{x_2-x_1}{x-x_1} \right)f(x)\ ,
\end{align}
which again implies $\ f(x)>0\ $.

Thus, $\ f\ $ has no other roots besides $\ x_1\ $ and $\ x_2\ $.

Answer (score 0):

There are no strictly convex functions with more than two zeros. Assume otherwise so that there are three points such that $f(a)=f(b)=f(c)=0$ with $a < b< c$. Since a function is convex if and only if its epigraph is a convex set we consider the line segment from $(a,f(x))$ to $(c,f(c))$ on the graph. This segment necessarily intersects $(b,f(b))$ so there exist some $t \in [0,1]$ such that $(a,f(x))+t((b,f(b))-(a,f(a))=(b,f(b))$ violating strict convexity.